# When onclick go to div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have something that I need help with. I want to click on an image and when I click I want to go to the `div`.

This is the code that I have and if you copy this and try it yourself, you will see that when I click on the image a `div` is opened but if I have many images I won't know where is open so I want to go to the `div` when I click on the image.

```
<img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/taboo_tom_hardy_2017-wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Taboo">
<div id="modal01" class="w3-modal w3-black w3-padding-0" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
    <span class="w3-closebtn w3-text-white w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off w3-xxlarge w3-container w3-display-topright">×</span>
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-center w3-transparent w3-padding-64">
      <img id="img01" class="w3-image">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function onClick(element) {
    document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
    document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    captionText.innerHTML = element.alt;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it will be on pure js.
But in JQ you can use next()

```
  <img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/taboo_tom_hardy_2017-wide.jpg" style="width:100%" class="click_image" alt="Taboo">
  <div id="modal01" class="w3-modal w3-black w3-padding-0" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
        <span class="w3-closebtn w3-text-white w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off w3-xxlarge w3-container w3-display-topright">×</span>
        <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-center w3-transparent w3-padding-64">
          <img id="img01" class="w3-image">
          <p id="caption"></p>
        </div>
   </div>
```

And in jq:

```
$('.click_image').click(function(){
 var alt=$(this).attr('alt');
$(this).next().find('#caption').html(alt);
});
```

But it will work if you have div after each image.
if you have many images and one div with id modal01? then use this:

```js
$('.click_image').click(function(){
 var alt=$(this).attr('alt');
$('div#modal01').show(0).find('#caption').html(alt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/taboo_tom_hardy_2017-wide.jpg" style="width:100%" class="click_image" alt="Taboo">
<img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/thumbs/2017/power_rangers_2017_4k_8k-t2.jpg" style="width:100%" class="click_image" alt="Rangers">
<img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/thumbs/2014/titanic-t2.jpg" style="width:100%" class="click_image" alt="Titanic">
      <div id="modal01" class="w3-modal w3-black w3-padding-0" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
            <span class="w3-closebtn w3-text-white w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off w3-xxlarge w3-container w3-display-topright">×</span>
            <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-center w3-transparent w3-padding-64">
              <img id="img01" class="w3-image">
              <p id="caption"></p>
            </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is scrolling to div when click on the image, you can use:

> [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView): he Element.scrollIntoView() method scrolls the element on which it's called into the visible area of the browser window.

The snippet:

```js
function onClick(element) {
  document.getElementById('modal01').scrollIntoView();
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/taboo_tom_hardy_2017-wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Taboo">
<div id="modal01" class="w3-modal w3-black w3-padding-0" onclick="this.style.display='none'">
    <span class="w3-closebtn w3-text-white w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off w3-xxlarge w3-container w3-display-topright">×</span>
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-center w3-transparent w3-padding-64">
        <img id="img01" class="w3-image">
        <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```